# Spring Boot 2.5 SocketTimeoutException only in Github Actions

Tags: spring-boot

I think that an upgrade from Spring Boot 2.4.8 to 2.5.2 is breaking my build, but I can't reproduce it locally. Has anyone seen this before? How can I fix or debug further?

Situation:

- Spring Boot 2.5.2 w/ Java 16

  - Runs locally
  - Unit tests pass locally via Intellij Runner
  - Unit tests pass locally via Gradle `./gradlew clean test`

Unit tests fail on Github Actions with Action:

```
  unit-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build-image

    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up JDK 16
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 16

      - name: Make gradle wrapper executable
        run: chmod +x gradlew

      - name: Run Unit Tests
        run: ./gradlew clean test
```

The first unit test that is run fails, with error:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at ConstructorResolver.java:658
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException at SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at ConstructorResolver.java:658
                    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException at SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185
                        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.java:107
                            Caused by: com.nimbusds.jose.RemoteKeySourceException at RemoteJWKSet.java:167
                                Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException at NioSocketImpl.java:283
```

All subsequent tests fail with error:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at ConstructorResolver.java:658
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException at SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185
                Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException at DbException.java:622
                    Caused by: java.net.BindException at Net.java:-2
```

Reverting back to Spring Boot 2.4.8 results in tests passing in Github Actions.

To restate, I think that an upgrade to from 2.4.8 to 2.5.2 is breaking my CI build in Github Actions, where that same upgrade has no effect locally. Across both versions, at no time is my local build broken. Unit tests pass locally on both versions, and the application runs as I expect it to on both versions. It is only on Github Actions, and only on Spring Boot 2.5.2 that unit tests fail.

The specific error messages make me feel that the changes described in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes might have an impact, particularly around the JDBC connection. Particularly since the error messages contain issues about socket timeouts and JDBCSqlNonTransientConnectionExceptions - but if it's a config issue, would that not also break locally? All my config is version controlled YAML files. If this was the issue I would expect the application to fail to connect to a database locally.

For completeness, here is the application.yml file I am running:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    database: h2
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
      hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
      hibernate.generate_statistics: false
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      settings:
        web-allow-others: true
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:api;MODE=PostgreSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    username: sa
    password: ____
    hikari:
      poolName: Hikari
      auto-commit: false
  flyway:
    locations: classpath:db/migration/database_structure,classpath:db/migration/sample-data
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:api;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
    user: sa
    password: ____
logging:
  level:
    nz.ringfence.valuable.api: DEBUG
h2:
  tcp:
    enabled: true

info:
  app:
    name: 'API - Dev'
    deploy_date: ${HEROKU_RELEASE_CREATED_AT}
    git_commit: ${HEROKU_SLUG_COMMIT}

sentry:
  environment: heroku-dev
```

Comment: It might be worth looking at increasing the [timeout](https://github.com/okta/okta-jwt-verifier-java/issues/7) for accessing the JWKS endpoint in the nimbus library. If you google `com.nimbusds.jose.RemoteKeySourceException` you will find a number of people have issues with timeouts.

Comment: Hey @Alex, how have you solved the problem? I just encountered the same issue.

Comment: Hi @Georgi - I fixed this by holding at 2.4.8 until October when 2.5.5 released. I skipped 2.5.2 entirely.

Comment: Thx! I guess I will have to get my hands dirty since in my case it happens on Spring Boot 2.5.13 and only on Jenkins. The local executions succeed :/